# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jhdf5 in java.library.path

Tags: java, scala, hdf5, saddle

I get the above error while running a Scala Saddle 1.3.4 application that saves and loads h5 files.

I have already tried without success configuring the following (Win64):

- `-Djava.library.path=C:\Dev\Tools\HDF5\1.10.0\lib\`
- `-Djava.library.path=C:\Dev\Tools\HDF5\1.10.0\lib\jarhdf5-1.10.0.jar`
- `-Dnative.libpath.jhdf5=C:\Dev\Tools\HDF5\1.10.0\lib\hdf5_java.dll`
- `-Dnative.libpath=C:\Dev\Tools\HDF5\1.10.0\lib\`

as well as a few other alternatives but I still get the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jhdf5 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.H5.loadH5Lib(H5.java:347)
    at ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.H5.<clinit>(H5.java:274)
    at ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.HDF5Constants.<clinit>(HDF5Constants.java:28)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$$anonfun$createFile$1.apply$mcI$sp(H5Store.scala:291)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$$anonfun$createFile$1.apply(H5Store.scala:290)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$$anonfun$createFile$1.apply(H5Store.scala:290)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$.org$saddle$io$H5Store$$withMonitor(H5Store.scala:49)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$.createFile(H5Store.scala:290)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$.org$saddle$io$H5Store$$writePandasFrame(H5Store.scala:1029)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$$anonfun$writeFrame$1.apply$mcI$sp(H5Store.scala:210)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$$anonfun$writeFrame$1.apply(H5Store.scala:210)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$$anonfun$writeFrame$1.apply(H5Store.scala:210)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$.org$saddle$io$H5Store$$withMonitor(H5Store.scala:49)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$.writeFrame(H5Store.scala:209)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Implicits$$anon$1.writeHdfFile(H5Implicits.scala:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.juliusbaer.example.Main$.main(Main.scala:30)
    at com.juliusbaer.example.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.H5.H5dont_atexit()I
    at ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.H5.H5dont_atexit(Native Method)
    at ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.H5.loadH5Lib(H5.java:365)
    at ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.H5.<clinit>(H5.java:274)
    at ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.HDF5Constants.<clinit>(HDF5Constants.java:28)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$$anonfun$createFile$1.apply$mcI$sp(H5Store.scala:291)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$$anonfun$createFile$1.apply(H5Store.scala:290)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$$anonfun$createFile$1.apply(H5Store.scala:290)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$.org$saddle$io$H5Store$$withMonitor(H5Store.scala:49)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$.createFile(H5Store.scala:290)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$.org$saddle$io$H5Store$$writePandasFrame(H5Store.scala:1029)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$$anonfun$writeFrame$1.apply$mcI$sp(H5Store.scala:210)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$$anonfun$writeFrame$1.apply(H5Store.scala:210)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$$anonfun$writeFrame$1.apply(H5Store.scala:210)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$.org$saddle$io$H5Store$$withMonitor(H5Store.scala:49)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$.writeFrame(H5Store.scala:209)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Implicits$$anon$1.writeHdfFile(H5Implicits.scala:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.juliusbaer.example.Main$.main(Main.scala:30)
    at com.juliusbaer.example.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: I solved this by downloading HDFView and then adding the following in path 
`-Dncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.H5.hdf5lib=C:\HDFView\2.13.0\lib\jhdf5.dll`

Comment: where do you add this?

Comment: For those trying to use HDFView, I fixed this by adding "<path to app>/HDFViewApp-3.1.2-win10_64-vs16\HDFView\app\bin" to the path environment variable, then relaunching cmd

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when just launching the binary on a windows OS. After launching the `HDFView.exe` a command window popped up, and closed again.

After launching it via a CLI I saw error you mentioned:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jhdf5 in java.library.path
```

I solved it with @kaladin anwser from above: I added the path `<path to app>/HDFViewApp-3.1.2-win10_64-vs16\HDFView\app\bin` to the **PATH** system enviornment variable. After saving it, I restarted the EXE file and it worked directly as expected!

Comment: Where do you download the lib ? https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdf5/ ?
I see no jhdf5 dll

Comment: You can download `HDFView.exe` tool on the page: https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdfview/ 

There you can download the files, depending on your OS. After installation, or inside the packages, you will find the libs.

Comment: How does one solve this on a mac?

Comment: Please check how to configure the system environment PATH variable in MacOS! It should be straight forward to add the complete path to the HDFView "bin"-Directory as mentioned by me above.